# Geocoding service for a startup?

Tags: google-maps, gis, geocoding, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an idea for a service that uses geocoded data (lat/lng) form a US address. Google maps API v3 has been awesome, until I read the terms of service and acceptable uses a little closer. The problem is that the terms seem to prohibit use of the maps API for any commercial use where the site is not freely accessibly to the public, such as a subscription based service. The alternative offered is Google Maps API Premier, but at $10,000 per year minimum, it's just not possible at this time.

Same goes for services offered by Yahoo! and MS - initial fees are small for enterprises, but for a very early stage startup (not even a finished prototype yet!) it's just not doable.

Geocoding process needs to be real-time and volume would be very small - user would enter address at setup time and only update it if needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not make it free during your 'beta phase'?

Comment: As Kenny said. Beta = testing, take Google checkout for instance, it was free to use during beta.

Comment: I can make it public for beta period, but the problem is that there is a component of the service that has a direct variable usage cost, so even if I derive no profit, it's still not free to use. (It's bring your own provider service, so I'm not charging, some one else is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used geocoder.us for a few projects.  They do require sign up for a commercial license, on the upside it only costs $50 per 20,000 lookups.  I haven't used their commercial services though to know how reliable they are, but during startup and especially because there will primarily only be one lookup per user from what you say, this seems like a safe bet.

Comment: I looked at them, but from their site I couldn't tell if the project was still active. Good to know they are still around.

Comment: As of April 8 they had just put up some news on the site.  So I'm assuming they still are.

Comment: Just tried to geocode "los angeles, ca 90001" and that didn't work:
http://geocoder.us/demo.cgi?address=los+angeles,+ca+90001   I'm guessing it needs full address.

Comment: My apologies that's all I've ever used it for so I didn't even think about that.

Comment: In an attempt to redeem myself I did a google search and found this service by USC: https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/
First 2500 lookups are free, after that you can continue to use it for free but you have to request more lookups manually through their site and put a link up back to their site.  Otherwise it looks like you can purchase 10,000 lookups for $20.
https://webgis.usc.edu/About/UsageCosts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The software company I work for (Safe Software) has incorporated a geocoding service into our product (FME). The service is [pxpoint](http://www.faspatial.com/products/applications/pxpoint) from Proxix. I hear good things, so perhaps it's worth checking them out?

Comment: Any pricing info you could share? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WorldWeatherOnline offers a geocoding API as part of their weather forecast service. The accuracy isn't great though. In some parts of my country, I'm getting bogus results. Their support has not been helpful in this matter.