# Window phone how to do reverse geocoding ? Get address from lattitude and longitude?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Window phone how to do reverse geocoding ? Get address from lattitude and longitude ?

If we use following link
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/point?includeEntityTypes=entityTypes&includeNeighborhood=includeNeighborhood&key=BingMapsKey

it gives correct response but it also says

Copyright © 2012 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.

So can we use this service ?

Comment: Try with this also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2013/06/14/reverse-geocoding-in-windows-phone-8.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps API can be used to do this. For a given Latitude/Longitude comibantion, call the url -

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
```

This will return a json object which you can process and show in your app.

To use this API, you need to go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ As a free user, you can only request 2,500 conversions a day.

Comment: Google provides paid services for higher demands. I am not sure of the prices. You can look at this answer for more information -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759361/geocoding-service-for-a-startup

Answer (score 0):

I would use google's web services.  Depending on how many you need to do per day, you may have to pay for a premium account, but it's priced reasonably if you need the service.

Comment: nope, you can use bing map for the map but google geoservice for the geocode. it is more accurate too.